# The difference between PHP operators

Tags: php

What is the difference between these PHP operators?

```
$str = 'ok';
$chkStr1 = isset($str) ? true : false;  // will output true
$chkStr2 = (isset($str)) ? true : false;  // will output true
$chkStr3 = (isset($str) ? true : false);  // will output true
```

The result is the same for all three

Comment: Why would there be a difference? They're all the same, plus or minus some superfluous parentheses.

Comment: No difference, ternary operator : condition executes first and then based on output one or another value assigned to variable

Comment: That's like asking the difference for `1 + 1`, `(1) + 1` and `(1 + 1)`.

Comment: parentheses are for setting precedence , but you only have a single ternary operator so if you add more parentheses it will make no difference (for your case)